# BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate Factory method '####' threw exception with message: Input must be set

Tags: selenium, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-spring

I am running selenium cucumber tests with spring configuration.
I have created beans for all pages and autowired them in all steps classes.
i created a cucumberspringconfig file as well
When running as maven test run i get the below error

```
 by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.deko.automation.pages.AvailableOffersPage]: Factory method 'availableOffersPage' threw exception with message: Input must be set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    ... 62 more
```

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/test/resources/features/"},
    glue = {"cucumber.steps", "com.deko.automation"},
    tags = "@test",
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/report/cucumber-report", "json:target/report/cucumber.json"},
    monochrome = true)
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {}
```

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config.class})
@ComponentScan({"com.deko.automation.cucumber.pages"})
@CucumberContextConfiguration()
@SpringBootTest
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {

  /** Dummy method to tell cucumber to initialise this class */
  @Before
  public void setUp() {}
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Bean
  @Lazy
  @Scope("cucumber-glue")
  public AvailableOffersPage availableOffersPage() {
    return new AvailableOffersPage();
  }
```

```
public class OffersPageSteps {

  @Autowired
  AvailableOffersPage availableOffersPage;
  @Autowired
  CreditApplicationPage creditApplicationPage;

  @Given("I select first offer and apply")
  public void selectFirstOfferandApply() {
    availableOffersPage.selectFirstOfferAndClickApply();
    creditApplicationPage.clickOnCompletePurchaseButton();
  }
}
```

```
@Scope(SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE)
@Component
public class AvailableOffersPage extends BasePage {

  @FindBy(xpath = "//button[@data-testid='apply-button']")
  private WebElement applyButton;

  @FindBy(xpath = "//div[text()='Representative Example']")
  private WebElement representativeExampleText;

  @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@data-testid='offer-container']")
  private WebElement firstOffer;

  @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@data-testid='trigger-close']")
  private WebElement triggerCloseButton;

  public void selectFirstOfferAndClickApply() {
    switchToIframe(getDriver(), 0);
    triggerCloseButton.click();
    scrollIntoView(getDriver(), firstOffer);
    waitForElementAndClick(30, firstOffer);
    scrollToTheEndOfPage(getDriver());
    applyButton.click();
    waitTillElementIsInvisible(getDriver(), applyButton);
  }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: error occurs here]

I tried to run the tests and got the above error 'Input must be set'
I dont understand what input AvailableoffersPage is expecting when initialising
Also it actually fails in basepage constructor

Comment: please post your code as a text, not as a picture

Comment: thx. posted the same code in pics as text

Answer (score 0):

My driver was null in the arguments being passed to webdriver wait. I put if statement to check if driver is null and it is. so initiated the page class where driver was setup and it is fixed.